# Unable to Copy JSON Lines file format in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to run a simple 'Copy Activity' in Azure Data Factory v2, to copy a JSON Lines file with the format .jsonl. However, I keep on getting the following error when I try to copy:

```
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=JsonInvalidDataFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file 'grantofrepresentation-2019-08.jsonl'. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,Message=Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'ce_data_classification.solsDeceasedAliasNamesList.value', line 2535, position 9228.,Source=Newtonsoft.Json,'
```

I'm sure ADF can handle .jsonl files but I have never worked with .jsonl files before.

Can someone confirm ADFv2 can copy .jsonl files, and let me know where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and Data Factory supports the JSON format file which end with ".jsonl" , see my example:
[image]

Please make sure you have set the JSON format as the dataset:
[image]

Ref： [JSON format in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json)

Comment: That is not a JSONL file in other than the name. Actual JSONL files contain one JSON object per line, so they are not JSON as such. Example:

[{'id':1, 'name': 'test'}]<br>
[{'id':2, 'name': 'another'}]